If X and Y are uncorrelated, i.e., $Cov(X,Y) = 0$, then $E[Y | X] = c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
It is given that X and Y are random variables on a common probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$.
Prove or disprove the following statement: If X and Y are uncorrelated, i.e., $Cov(X,Y) = 0$, then $E[Y | X] = c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
Additionally, I have already shown the other direction, i.e., that from $E[Y | X] = c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, it follows that X and Y are uncorrelated, but I am uncertain about whether the other direction holds; I am having difficulty showing that the conditional expectation is constant.
Here is the proof for the other direction: $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY)-E(X)E(Y) = E[E[XY|X]] - E(X)\cdot E[E[Y|X]]$ (here: $E[E[XY|X]] = E[XE[Y|X]] = E[X\cdot c] = c\cdot E[X]$; $E[E[Y|X]] = E[c]$) $= c\cdot E[X] - c\cdot E[X] = 0$.

This is false in general, it becomes true if $(X,Y)$ is normal beause then $X$, $Y$ are independent.

This is false. A counterexample would be: $X \sim \mathcal{U}[-1, 1]$ and $Y = \cos(X)$. Then, $\text{Cov}(X, Y) = 0$ but $\mathbb{E}(Y \vert X) = \cos(X)$

Nice counterexample! Thank you!
